# Scala Reflection Search?

Tags: scala, reflection

As a bit of thought exercise, I'm wondering if it's possible to make a scala trait that does a deep search within the current object for other items meeting that definition, and envoking them. For example:

```
trait CanDebug { this =>

  def depthFirstDebug(level:Int) {
    for ( x<-(this object search matching type CanDebug)) {
      x.depthFirstDebug(level+1)

    }
    println("level "+level+" "+this.toString)
  }

}

case class A (s:String) extends CanDebug 

class B extends CanDebug {
  val a1 = A("Hello")      //automatically located by CanDebug by it's type
  val a2 = A("World")
  override def toString = "Start"
}

val b =new B
b.depthFirstDebug(0)
```

Output something to the effect of:

Level 1 Hello
Level 1 World
Level 0 Start

Using Scala 2.10.2 and I believe this should be possible using reflection, but i'm unsure of the logistics. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mirrors to reflect on `this` and then invoke the desired method:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

def depthFirstDebug(level:Int) {
  val mirror = currentMirror.reflect(this)
  val tpe = mirror.symbol.typeSignature

  for {
    m <- tpe.members
    if  m.typeSignature <:< typeOf[CanDebug]
    if  m.isTerm
    if !m.isMethod
  } {
    val fld = mirror.reflectField(m.asTerm)
    fld.get.asInstanceOf[CanDebug].depthFirstDebug(level + 1)
  }
  println("level "+level+" "+this.toString)
}
```

Now you can:

```
val b =new B
b.depthFirstDebug(0)
```

Which gives you:

```
level 1 A(World)
level 1 A(Hello)
level 0 Start
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the information, it seems a lot of Scala info out there on reflection assumes advanced knowledge of the topic.. and my scala book has yet to catch up on 2.10 trying to learn the basics!

Comment: Have some serious problems in Intellij with the latest scala version 2.10.2 what gives? object runtime is not a member of package reflect
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
                     ^

Comment: Found it.. Intellij by default seems to exclude several scala jars,just added it as a dependancy .. scala-reflect.jar